# hiding div when the form is submitted successfully

Tags: php, css

I would like to hide the div and show another one if the form is submitted successfully, I guess I have to use jquery's `.hide()` and `.show()` classes but I don't know how. Can someone help me out?

css

```
 .hidden{display:none}
 .main{}
```

php

```
  <div class="main>
  <form action="" method="post">
  <!--all the stuff to be hidden goes here-->
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden">
   <div>Form has been successfully submitted</div><!-- will be visible upon successful form submision-->
  </div
  <?php
  if(isset($_post['submit']){
     if(!empty($var_1) || !empty($var_2))
       {
       //insert in to database
       //success
       }
       else{
          //something is wrong.
        }
      }
```

Comment: submitted how? to itself or by ajax?

Comment: @davidkonrad to itself

Comment: is there any JavaScript involved when submitting the form?

Comment: @DanielLisik There is none. I am just submitting the form to the same page. `action=""` it's php page.

Comment: @user3006683 Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if ( isset($_post['submit']) && (!empty($var_1) || !empty($var_2) ) {

    //insert in to database

} else {
?>

<form ...>
</form>

<?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have solved it like this:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_post['submit']){ // Form is submitted
 if(!empty($var_1) || !empty($var_2))

   { // success, insert in to database

   ?>

 <div class="hidden">
 <div>Form has been successfully submitted</div>
 <!-- will be visible upon successful form submision-->
 </div

<?php
   } // success, insert in to database

   else { // something is wrong.

?> 

 <form action="" method="post">
 <!--all the stuff to be hidden goes here-->
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

<?php
    } // something is wrong.
  } // Form is submitted
?>
```